# How to hide some Eclipse autocomplete results

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I'm developing Wicket applications in Eclipse 3.6. Is there a way to block out some packages from Eclipse autocomplete, so that I don't see suggestions for the unwanted AWT classes with the same name? I'd like to see the `org.apache.wicket` result below, but not the `java.awt` result.

[image: Wicket TextField, not AWT please]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check this out:

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters
```

and add the `java.awt` package

Comment: Thanks - I'd completely missed that preference page. At least the search I was trying will find this answer in the future.

Comment: Yes it is very easy to miss this as I always think its in *Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist*.