# What should I be using instead of com.google.appengine.repackaged*?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Just updated to 1.6.1 and I am getting warnings that I should not be using

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged
```

What should I be using instead?

Affected classes specifically are:

> com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.json.JSONException;
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.util.Base64;
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.util.Base64DecoderException;

Comment: By way of background, until 1.6.1 (and the corresponding Google Plugin for Eclipse), Eclipse would happily reach in to the App Engine SDK, letting you use bits that are really implementation details that we're reserving the right to change (likely without warning). To head off sudden, unpleasant surprises, we arranged for the warning you're getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `org.json.*` you can use the Java JSON library found at http://json.org/ (though there are other, better JSON libraries for Java)

For classes in `com.google.common.*` you can find most of them (though not `Base64`, etc., apparently) in [Google's Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Comment: Base64 is now included in Guava (as of 2013-02).

Comment: Base64 was never part of Guava. If you want to do base64 encoding/decoding with Guava, please use com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.base64() instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
org.json.JSONException;
org.json.JSONObject;
com.google.common.util.Base64;
com.google.common.util.Base64DecoderException;
```

Comment: it seems JSONException does not exist in org.json

Comment: @Lumpy, Yes it does.  See the [Javadoc](http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONException.html)

Comment: sorry I meant org.json included in appengine doesn't have it, once I included my own jar it works.

Comment: Do you know where I can dl a jar for com.google.common.util.Base64DecoderException;

Comment: I suspect that that is one of the classes that Google developed internally and has not yet packaged into a public release of Guava.

Comment: Speaking as a Guava developer, Guava doesn't control `common.util`.  I'm not sure what the AppEngine guys were doing, but this is not something that Guava has any plans to provide.

Were you using Base64 for your own purposes, or do you need it to build AppEngine?

Comment: Personally, I need it so I can use appengine classes clientside in a gwt project.  I would very much like to be sending base64 encoded strings to the client and decoding there, so I don't have to send my keys in cleartext over the wire.  Perhaps the Base64 encoder is too expensive to use in gwt, and I will have to come up with my own encoding, but it would be optimal to construct properly encoded keys in the client.

Answer (score 2):

You should include third party jars yourself in your application, instead of relying on `com.google.appengine.repackaged`

In your case, your should add the following dependencies:

- [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)
- [JSON Java](http://json.org/java/)

Comment: json seemed to work but apache commons does not seem to be the same.  Is it possibly a different commons?

Comment: I believe the apache version provide similar feature see: http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: why does Google repackage 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225680/google-app-engine-repackaged-package